# How to combine 3 tables using SQL?

Tags: sql

How can I combine results of 2 table into 3rd table?

These are 3 different tables

Table A

| AC_ID | IDNT_ID | ID_DESC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | a1000 | mhyed |
| *456* | *b2000* | *DL* |
| 769 | c2000 |  |
| **246** | **2000d** | **BCD** |
| 357 | 3000f |  |
| 567 | 600d | uhj |

Table B:

| b_id | b_no |
| --- | --- |
| *b2000* | *7000001* |
| d78987 | 909898 |

Table C:

| c_id | c_no |
| --- | --- |
| **2000d** | **678987** |
| 6789 | 09876 |

Table D: it is a table of all records from table A and common between A& B and A&C

| AC_ID | IDNT_ID | No | ID_DESC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | a1000 |  | mhyed |
| *456* | *b2000* | *7000001* | *DL* |
| 769 | c3000 |  |  |
| **246** | **2000d** | **678987** | **BCD** |
| 357 | 3000f |  |  |
| 567 | 600d |  | uhj |

What would be SQL to get the result of table D ?

Table E: is the combination of Table B& C

| header 1 | header 2 |
| --- | --- |
| b2000 | 700001 |
| d78987 | 909898 |
| 2000d | 678987 |
| 6789 | 09876 |

What would be SQL to get the result of table D ? also what would be SQL table E?

I tried using union and joins but was not able to get desired result

Comment: Post the query you have tried so far so we can help guide you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your sample data for tbl_a, tbl_b and tbl_c **use Left Joins for tbl_b and tbl_c** to get the result shown as "Table D":

```sql
-- Table D SQL
Select
    a.AC_ID "AC_ID",
    a.IDNT_ID "IDNT_ID",
    COALESCE(b.B_NO, c.C_NO) "B_C_NO",
    a.ID_DESC "ID_DESC"
From
    tbl_a a
Left Join
    tbl_b b ON(b.B_ID = a.IDNT_ID)
Left Join
    tbl_c c ON(c.C_ID = a.IDNT_ID)
Order By
    a.AC_ID
    
/*  R e s u l t :
|     AC_ID |IDNT_ID |B_C_NO  |ID_DESC|
|---------- |------- |------- |-------|
|       123 |a1000   |        |mhyed  | 
|       246 |2000d   |678987  |BCD    | 
|       357 |3000f   |        |       | 
|       456 |b2000   |7000001 |DL     | 
|       567 |600d    |        |uhj    | 
|       769 |c2000   |        |       | 
*/
```

... and for "Table E" you just need to **union tables tbl_b and tbl_c**:

```sql
-- Table E SQL
Select B_ID "HEADER_1", B_NO "HEADER_2" From tbl_b Union All
Select C_ID "HEADER_1", C_NO "HEADER_2" From tbl_c

/*  R e s u l t :
HEADER_1 HEADER_2
-------- --------
b2000    7000001  
d78987   909898   
2000d    678987   
6789     09876  
*/
```

Regards...

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering how we can using Coalesce function. This is a good example to understand Coalesce for me.